# Cloned repository doesn't have working functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I created a project on Github, then cloned the completed project to my local machine. I renamed the main directory and removed remote. I then reinitialized git to a new remote in a new Git repository hosting service and then pushed:

```
git push -u origin --all
```

Trying to run site, I am notified to run a migration.

```
rails db:migrate:reset
```

Everything seems fine until I run on localhost. The data that was uploaded is no longer there, which is expected, but I can't seem to signup as a new user.

In addition, there is a text that are links that do not lead anywhere, even though in the file they are not marked up as links.

The site is built on Rails and functions fine in the original repository. It is only when I run the cloned site where things are off.

Any insight will be appreciated.
If you are going to downvote, at least tell me why.
Constructive feedback beats a negative score anyday.

Comment: What happens when you sign up a user, what are you expecting exactly? Show us content of file that creates links and also inspect the HTML generated and show us.

Comment: It's also possible environment variables are being loaded from a file in the `.gitignore` file in the original repo. This could potentially affect things like URLs.

Comment: @fbelanger I fill the signup form and when I click submit, nothing happens.

Comment: @dinjas I didn't think about that. Let me dig deeper and see what I can find.

Comment: @limaBEAN Devise? Any error messages when starting up server? Any when submitting sign up? Edit post and add funky text links file.

Comment: @fbelanger Devise, yes. Error messages, besides the initial message that prompted to run a migration, no. The hover action works and when I submit the button it shows it's being pressed. However, nothing renders in the logs and I am not taken to the next view. I've even tried to not meet the password criteria, no luck.

Comment: You can also use the browser to inspect the form markup and see if the URL looks correct. It's possible it's attempting to POST elsewhere

Comment: The URLs are fine. I am not sure what happened during this project, but after cloning a different site project to see if I will run into the same problem, I realized I am able to run that site fine. I am just going to go ahead and redo this problem project because trying to fix this clone has taken more time than creating a new project and starting from scratch. Thanks for the input you all. I may come back to this particular master project to figure out what went wrong. If I do find out, I'll post solution here.